# tKinter Multithreading Stopping a Thread

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, python-multithreading

I have created a Python GUI with tKinter in my simple example I have a button that triggers a simple loop that increments a counter. I have succesfully threaded the counter so my GUI won't freeze, however I am having issues with getting it to stop counting. Here is my code:

```
# threading_example.py
import threading
from threading import Event
import time
from tkinter import Tk, Button


root = Tk()

class Control(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.my_thread = None
        self.stopThread = False

    def just_wait(self):
        while not self.stopThread:
            for i in range(10000):
                time.sleep(1)
                print(i)

    def button_callback(self):
        self.my_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.just_wait)
        self.my_thread.start()

    def button_callbackStop(self):
        self.stopThread = True
        self.my_thread.join()
        self.my_thread = None


control = Control()
button = Button(root, text='Run long thread.', command=control.button_callback)
button.pack()
button2 = Button(root, text='stop long thread.', command=control.button_callbackStop)
button2.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

How can I safely make the counter stop incrementing and gracefully close the thread?

Answer (score 1):

You have to check for `self.stopThread` inside the `for` loop

Comment: How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

So you want a for loop AND a while loop to run in parallel? Well they can't. As you have them, the for loop is running and won't pay attention to the while loop condition.

You need to make only a single loop. If you want your thread to auto terminate after 10000 cycles, you could do it like this:

```
def just_wait(self):
    for i in range(10000):
        if self.stopThread:
            break # early termination
        time.sleep(1)
        print(i)
```

Comment: Hey Johnathan thanks, I was having a brain fart moment.